# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

Tags: java, hibernate

I am following a you tube tutorial about Hibernate by Telusko Learnings.

But I keep getting the error in the subject.

I have checked my getters and setters for errors and there are none, there are no missing jars that Maven forgot to download and I am very frustrated.

I have shared the entire project and errors on Git Hub (https://github.com/ishonowo/hibernate-tut/tree/master/DemoHib).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While we are happy to help, it is expected for you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a specific problem you are facing in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score -1):

Stack trace offers all but enough information as to the cause of your error. As can see the reason why this fails is a missing class:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.util.proxy.MethodFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 23 more
```

My best guess is that your dependencies are wrong. I would go ahead and doublecheck them in order to be sure.